DataBase erase element with SQLite in Maui Android
I have an Endpoint from which I collect some data from some clients.
I delete the Clients data table, create it and fill it with the data that I have collected from the Endpoint (I am using SQLite extensions) when I prees a Button.
  public async Task SynchronizeDataBase()

  { Clients = await restService.GetClients();
    App.ClientsRepo.DeleteTable<Clients>();
    App.ClientsRepo.CreateTable<Clients>();
    App.ClientsRepo.FillTable(Clients);
}

 public void DeleteTable<T>()
 {
     connection.DropTable<T>(); // I have tested it with DeleteAll, but I have the same problem
 }

I have a 1:1 waterfall relationship with an order. It turns out that every time I sync with the endpoint to collect the data again, the Client data from the Order table is deleted and remains null... I have tried deleting Cascade operations from the Order table, but I still have the same problem . I don't understand why this happens, if I'm just deleting the Clients table. I have tried DeleteAll and DropTable by calling the Delete() method;
 public class TableData
 {
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int Id { get; set; }
 }

 public class Clients : TableData
 {
     public int IdEmpresa { get; set; }
     public string razon_social { get; set; }
     public string cif { get; set; }
     public int IdFormaPago { get; set; }
     public int IdVencimiento { get; set; }
     public float descuento { get; set; }
     public float DescuentoPP { get; set; }
     public float retencion { get; set; }
     public float diaPago1 { get; set; }
     public float diaPago2 { get; set; }     

 }

public class Order : TableData
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }                           
    public int PaymentMethodId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; } = 1;
    private bool IsSynchronized { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; } 


    [ForeignKey(typeof(Clients))]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)] // I have Deleted CascadeOperations, but the    same problem..

    public Clients Client { get; set; }


Why is the Client field deleted when I delete the data table, if I do not touch the Order table

every time I sync with the endpoint to collect the data again, the Client data from the Order table is deleted and remains null... Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on your problem? What do you mean by words I sync with the endpoint to collect the data again? How do you collect the data again? If it is convenient for you, could you please share the steps of reproducing this problem and a basic demo here so that we can try to reproduce this problem?
